# List of all permissions

Tags: global-payments-api

I have been looking like all over the place for a complete list of permissions for Global Payments `UCP` APIs. Of course I have a developer account and I searched their Github yaml files but cannot find a complete list.

```
    TRN_POST_INITIATE
    TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
    TRN_POST_Reauthorize
    TRN_POST_Capture_Multiple
    TRN_POST_Authorize
    TRN_POST_Adjust
    TRN_POST_Refund
    TRN_POST_Confirm
    TRN_POST_Reverse
    TRN_POST_Capture
    TRN_GET_Single
    TRN_GET_List_Funded_Fees
    TRN_GET_List
    TRN_POST_Force
    VER_POST_Verify

    ACT_POST_Multiple
    ACT_GET_Single
    ACT_GET_List
    ACT_POST_Auto_Action

    AUT_POST_Results
    AUT_POST_Initiate
    AUT_POST_Check_Availability

    GET_Single
    
    CCS_POST_DCC
    CCS_GET_Bin_Ranges
    
    ACC_GET_List
    ACC_GET_Single
    
    DEV_POST_Sync

    BAT_GET_Single
    BAT_POST_Close

    PMT_PATCH_Edit
    PMT_POST_Create_Single
```

I am most interested in the ones related to `payment-methods` at the moment.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would also like to know this. Is there a * permission that grants everything?

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from the source code of the dashboard where you set permissions for an account.

```
dcc_p
permissions

BAT_GET_Single
APP_GET_List
TRN_POST_Incremental
ACC_GET_List
ACC_GET_Single_Platform
TRN_POST_Reauthorize
GET_Single
INS_POST_Query
TRN_POST_Split
TRN_POST_Authorize
VER_POST_Verify
ACC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Adjust
TRN_POST_Refund
TRN_GET_Single
APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
AUT_POST_Results
TRN_POST_Initiate
TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
APP_GET_Single
AUT_POST_Initiate
AUT_POST_Check_Availability
DEV_POST_Sync
ACT_POST_Multiple
CCS_POST_DCC
PFC_GET_List
BAT_POST_Close
TRN_POST_Reverse
TRN_POST_Confirm
PFC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Capture
ACT_GET_Single
TRN_GET_List
ACT_GET_List

paylink
permissions

LNK_POST_Create
LNK_POST_Expire
LNK_GET_List
LNK_GET_Single
LNK_PATCH_Edit
ACT_POST_Auto_Action

dcc
permissions

BAT_GET_Single
CCS_GET_Bin_Ranges
APP_GET_List
TRN_POST_Incremental
LNK_PATCH_Edit
ACC_GET_List
ACC_GET_Single_Platform
TRN_POST_Reauthorize
LNK_POST_Create
GET_Single
LNK_GET_List
INS_POST_Query
TRN_POST_Authorize
VER_POST_Verify
ACC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Adjust
TRN_POST_Refund
TRN_GET_Single
APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
AUT_POST_Results
TRN_POST_Initiate
TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
LNK_GET_Single
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
APP_GET_Single
AUT_POST_Initiate
LNK_POST_Expire
AUT_POST_Check_Availability
DEV_POST_Sync
ACT_POST_Multiple
CCS_POST_DCC
PFC_GET_List
BAT_POST_Close
TRN_POST_Confirm
TRN_POST_Reverse
PFC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Capture
ACT_GET_Single
TRN_GET_List
ACT_GET_List

dcc_rate
permissions

BAT_GET_Single
CCS_GET_Bin_Ranges
APP_GET_List
TRN_POST_Incremental
ACC_GET_List
ACC_GET_Single_Platform
TRN_POST_Reauthorize
GET_Single
INS_POST_Query
TRN_POST_Split
TRN_POST_Authorize
VER_POST_Verify
ACC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Adjust
TRN_POST_Refund
TRN_GET_Single
APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
AUT_POST_Results
TRN_POST_Initiate
TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
APP_GET_Single
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
AUT_POST_Initiate
DEV_POST_Sync
AUT_POST_Check_Availability
ACT_POST_Multiple
CCS_POST_DCC
PFC_GET_List
BAT_POST_Close
TRN_POST_Reverse
TRN_POST_Confirm
PFC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Capture
ACT_GET_Single
TRN_GET_List
ACT_GET_List

transaction_processing
permissions

APP_GET_List
TRN_POST_Incremental
LNK_PATCH_Edit
ACT_GET_Single_Logs
ACC_GET_List
LNK_POST_Create
LNK_GET_List
TRN_POST_Capture_Multiple
TRN_POST_Split
ACC_GET_Single
DEV_GET_Single
APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
AUT_POST_Results
TRN_POST_Hold
TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
DEV_GET_List
AUT_POST_Initiate
LNK_POST_Expire
DEV_POST_Sync
ACT_POST_Multiple
CCS_POST_DCC
BAT_POST_Close
INS_GET_List
PFC_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Capture
DEV_POST_Create
BAT_GET_Single
INS_GET_Single
ACC_GET_Single_Platform
TRN_POST_Reauthorize
GET_Single
INS_POST_Query
TRN_POST_Authorize
VER_POST_Verify
TRN_POST_Adjust
TRN_POST_Refund
TRN_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Initiate
LNK_GET_Single
APP_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Release
AUT_POST_Check_Availability
PFC_GET_List
TRN_POST_Confirm
TRN_POST_Reverse
ACT_GET_Single
TRN_POST_Force
TRN_GET_List
ACT_GET_List

settlement_reporting
permissions

APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
DIS_GET_List_Funded
DIS_GET_Single_Funded
FND_GET_List
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
TRN_GET_List_Funded
ACC_GET_List
GET_Single
DEP_GET_List
ACT_POST_Multiple
TRN_GET_Single_Funded
ACC_GET_Single
RPT_GET_Monthly_Fees_List
TRN_GET_List_Funded_Fees
DEP_GET_Single
ACT_GET_List

dispute_management
permissions

GET_Single
DIS_POST_Challenge
ACT_POST_Multiple
ACC_GET_Single
DIS_POST_Accept
DIS_GET_Lists
ACT_GET_Single
ACT_GET_List
DIS_GET_Single
ACC_GET_List

my_merchants
permissions

APP_GET_List
ACT_GET_Single_Logs
ACC_GET_List
MER_POST_Create
MER_ACT_GET_Single_Logs
MER_HLD
ACC_GET_Single
MER_TRN
MER_PFC
MER_LNK
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
MER_TRF
MER_ACT_POST_Multiple
ACT_POST_Multiple
MER_AUT
MER_GET_List
MER_GET_Single
MER_ACC_POST_Create
PFC_GET_Single
MER_DOC
MER_ACT
MER_CCS
MER_TRN_GET_Platform_References
MER_BIN
ACC_GET_Single_Platform
MER_PMT_POST_Detokenize
MER_VER
MER_APP
GET_Single
MER_RAS
MER_ACC_PATCH_Edit
MER_APP_GET_Single_Key
MER_FND
MER_REL
ADD_GET_List
MER_PMT
MER_BAT
MER_DEV
APP_GET_Single_Key
MER_INS
MER_ACC_GET_Single_Platform
APP_GET_Single
MER_ACC
MER_TRN_POST_Force
PFC_GET_List
MER_TRN_POST_Refund_Standalone
PFC_PATCH_Edit
ACT_GET_Single
MER_PATCH_Edit
ACT_GET_List

risk_assessment1
permissions

GET_Single
APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
PFC_GET_List
ACC_GET_Single
PFC_GET_Single
RAS_POST_Create
ACC_GET_List

EOS_RiskAssessment
permissions

APP_POST_Search_PFCValidate
GET_Single
ACC_GET_Single
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
RAS_POST_Create
ACC_GET_List

tokenization
permissions

PMT_POST_Create_Single
PMT_POST_Detokenize
PMT_POST_Search
ACT_POST_Auto_Action
PMT_GET_List
ACC_GET_List
GET_Single
PMT_POST_Create
ACT_POST_Multiple
PMT_Delete
ACC_GET_Single
PMT_GET_Single
PMT_PATCH_Edit
PYR_POST_Create
ACT_GET_Single
PYR_POST_Edit
ACT_GET_List
```